# What is the probability that player A rolls a larger number if player B is allowed to re-roll (20-sided die)?

Tags: probability, conditional-probability, dice

The problem statement is:

*2 players roll a 20-sided die. What is the probability that player A rolls a larger number if player B is allowed to re-roll a single time?*

The question is a bit ambiguous, but I am going to operate on the following 2 assumptions:

(a) Player B doesn't know what player A rolls when deciding whether or not to reroll.

(b) If player B re-rolls, his first roll is discarded. In other words, when comparing player A's roll to player B's roll, only the last roll of player B is taken into account.

(c) Player B doesn't want player A to win, so it will play optimally.

### I solved this problem, but it seems my solution does not match the answer given , which is $\frac{1}{4}$. Below is my solution process.

I know the following:

(1) Probability that A rolls a larger number if player B isn't allowed to re-roll. The probability that they roll the same number is $\frac{20}{400}$. The probability that player A rolls a larger number is thus $\frac{190}{400} = \frac{19}{40}$.

(2) How does player B decide if they should toss again? It's obvious to me that he should toss again if the first toss is $\leq 10$. If he tosses $> 10$, he should not toss again. So with probability $0.5$, he will get an expected value of $15.5$, and with probability $0.5$, he will toss again and get expected value $10.5.$

His expected outcome toss when considering that he can re-roll is thus
$$
E[B] = 0.5 \cdot 15.5 + 0.5 \cdot 10.5 = 13
$$

2.5 higher than the case where he isn't allowed to re-roll. Seems reasonable...

I found the threshold of $b = 10$ (where $b$ is the largest value on the first toss at which player B decides to do a second toss) by intuition, but we could have formulated an optimization problem
$$
\arg \max_b \frac{20-b}{20} \frac{20 + b + 1}{2} + \frac{b}{20} 10.5
$$

and solved for $b$ that maximizes $E[B]$.

Then I define disjoint events to be $B$ deciding to retoss (denote as $RR$) and $B$ deciding not retoss (denote as $NR$). Then we can write
$$
P(A > B) = P(A > B | RR) P(RR) + P(A > B | NR) P(NR)
$$

Previously we saw that $P(RR) = P(NR) = 0.5$.

For $P(A > B | RR)$, where player $B$ retosses, I believe the probability that I computed in (1) is the same as the conditional probability $P(A > B | RR)$, i.e., $P(A > B | RR) = \frac{19}{40}$. I think this is true because the die tosses are IID and memoryless. So that when $B$ retosses, we can treat this case as simply both $A$ and $B$ tossing a single time.

For $P(A > B | NR)$, when we condition on $NR$, i.e., $B$ stopping on the first toss, then this means that $B$ rolled a $11, 12, \ldots, 20$. There are $20 \cdot 10$ possibly outcomes for $(A,B)$ conditioned on $NR$. $9 + 8 + \ldots 1 = 45$ of these outcomes are such that $A > B$. So $P(A > B | NR) = \frac{45}{200} = \frac{9}{40}$

So $P(A > B) = \frac{19}{80} + \frac{9}{80} = \frac{28}{80} = \frac{7}{20}$ for the case where $B$ is allowed to re-toss. This is only $\frac{1}{8}$ less than the case where $B$ isn't allowed to re-toss. This seems reasonable.

I don't think I made a mistake in my solution, but it doesn't match $\frac{1}{4}$.

Comment: @lamanon is it given that  P(B goes for the second toss) = P(B dose't go for second toss)=1/2?

Comment: @Gingerbread It's not given, but I solved for it and found that the probability of it going for a second toss is 0.5 (I showed this in the post), and I believe that probability is correct. However note that player $B$ doesn't randomly go for a second toss. He operates based on the outcome of the first toss.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

What you have done looks right (and I've checked the calculations and get the same answer). In particular, if B doesn't know the result of A's roll, it is correct to reroll on 10 or below, and keep the original roll on 11 or above, since if B keeps a roll of $r$ the chance of B winning is $r/20$, whereas if B rerolls the chance of winning is $21/40$.

The value of $1/4$ cannot possibly be correct. Even if we give B every possible advantage, by letting them pick the higher of two rolls rather than having to choose before seeing the second (and assuming that A has to get strictly higher to win), A wins more than $1/4$ of the time. This is because if all three rolls are different, A wins with probability $1/3$, and all three rolls are different with probability $\frac{19}{20}\times\frac{18}{20}$, so A's chance of winning must be greater than $\frac{19}{20}\times\frac{18}{20}\times\frac13=0.285$. (In fact the exact value with these assumptions would be $\frac{247}{800}$.)

Comment: Was there an easier approach to arrive at my answer than what I went through? It seemed rather long, and I wasn't sure if there's some trick that would have simplified the problem.

Comment: The follow-up to this question was if $A$ now has a 30-sided die rather than 20-sided, would the threshhold found previously still be optimal for player $B$, who still rolls a 20-sided die? The way I solved the problem in the OP for deciding when $B$ should reroll, seems independent of how many sided die $A$ obtains. So my answer to this question would be that the threshhold would stay the same, but this seems weird to me. The book gives the solution of the threshhold being 11 instead of 10. Do you think the number of sides on player $A$'s die matters?

Comment: I just confirmed via monte carlo that a 30-sided die doesn't make a difference.

Comment: @Iamanon the reason it doesn't make a difference is that B has no chance unless A rolls 1-20 on the larger die, and if you condition on that happening, it's just as if A only had a 20-sided die. It would make a difference if A had a smaller die, though: if A had a 10-sided die, B should only reroll 7 or below.

Comment: Ah I see. I'm actually not sure how to solve for the case where $A$ has a lesser sided die. In my OP, I actually determined the threshhold without even thinking about $A$. I was only thinking about maximizing $B$, which occurs if re-roll if $B \leq 10$, which coincidentally matches the correct answer. So in other words, I actually found the right answer using an incorrect thought process. How do you actually solve it the correct way?

Comment: Also, btw, I asked a different follow-up question here https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/3782869/two-players-rolling-a-20-sided-die-player-b-can-re-roll-how-to-decide-when-to. feel free to chime in.

Comment: @Iamanon what you should do to work out the threshold is look at the probability of winning if you have a given number $r$, and reroll if this is less than its expectation. But if A has at least as large a die, the probability of winning if you have $r$ is just $r$ times a constant, so you can just look at the expectation of the number itself.

Comment: But if A has a lesser sided die, how do we determine that case? The “reroll of r is less than its expectation” wouldn’t apply in that case. For example if A has a 1 sided die, we would never want to reroll because any r is greater or equal to 1, but r here is still less than its expectation.

Comment: @Iamanon it's if the probability of winning is less than the expectation that matters. For a 10-sided die, the probability of winning is $r/10$ if $r\leq 10$ and $1$ otherwise. The expectation of the probability is the average of the values $0.1,0.2,...,0.9,1,1,...,1$, which works out at $0.775$, so you should reroll if the probability for your current value is less than this.

Comment: Hmm I see. Is that equivalent to solving for the threshhold $b$, such that $P(A > B) = \sum_{i=1}^{20} P(A>B | B = i) P(B = i) = P(A > B | B \leq b) P(B \leq b) + P(A > B | B > b) P(B>b)$

It seems in your comment, the case $P(B > b)$ / second roll is not considered.

Answer (score 1):

I think B is allowed to choose to rethrow after seeing A results.

Say that A wins if his result is strictly better than B's.

So if the first two throws are $(a_1, b_1)$ then B will rethrow iff $b_1 \le a_1 < m$ (where $m$ is the maximal value) so he'll have a chance to win with his second throw.

If we have a simple "two-sided die" (or coin, really) with equiprobable values $0,1$ to simplify, we have $4$ outcomes: $(0,0)$ (B throws again and wins with chance $\frac12$, otherwise we draw), $(0,1)$ terminates as B already won, $(1,0)$, B throws to avoid a loss, again with probability $\frac12$, $(1,1)$, the game is inevitably drawn. So A only wins in one scenario: first $(1,0)$ and B does not improve (total probability $\frac18$). B wins with $(0,1)$, and $(0,0)$ and improved toss, so $\frac14 + \frac18 = \frac38$, and finally we have a draw  when $(0,0)$ plus non-improvement, and $(1,1)$ and $(1,0)$ with improvement, so $\frac12$. So A/B/draw has chances $\frac{1/3/4}{8}$ resp. Now generalise to larger dice.